# How to copy only files (.wrk) from multiple directories and subfolders

Tags: command-line, files, directory, copy

I want to copy `.wrk` files from subfolders to onr WRK folder.

Example: 
I have one main folder (MIDI) and there is subfolders (named by numbers) 1 - 21 subfolders, which are under that main folder.

Each of those 21 subfolders has 2 - 5 subfolders. And those 2 - 5 subfolders may have 3 subfolders.

So, is it possible to copy (.wrk) files from all folders and subfolders to one  (WRK) folder which is under main folder (MIDI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use find:

```
cd /path/to/MIDI
find {1..21} -type f -name "*.wrk" -exec cp -i {} ./MIDI/WRK/ \;
```

it only search within 1 to 21 directories and all of their sub dirs for any files with ".wrk" suffix, then it moves all of them to "WRK".

using `-i` we make sure nothing will get over written,

Comment: @Jari You're welcome, you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful to you by clicking on the gray tick.

Comment: I done something wrong, because I get message in terminal: mv: cannot move ‘16/koe.wrk’ to ‘./MIDI/WRK’: No such file or directory

Comment: make sure `./MIDI/WRK` dir exists from where you are running the command.

Comment: Here is the path were I tried to use command:    computer@computer-desktop:~/Music/Midi_things/MIDI/WRK$

Comment: You have to be in `~/Music/Midi_things` to get the things works: `cd ~/Music/Midi_things`

Comment: I thought OP wanted to copy, not move

Comment: @Zanna OPS ... what did I've done :|

Comment: I get 39 files to WRK-folder.  I use this:    computer@computer-desktop:~/Music/Midi_things/MIDI$ find {1..21} -type f -name "*.wrk" -exec mv -i {} ./WRK/ \;
 
mv: overwrite ‘./WRK/mahetzuo2.wrk’?    Then I press enter every time when it came.  Don't worry, I have double files.

Comment: @Jari I wrote a wrong command, it doesn't copy the files, it moves them... don't use it... if you didn't till now, and change the `mv` to the `cp` in the command, just as I updated by answer.

Comment: Ravexina, dodn't worry, I have copies.  In my last message there is the command what I have used and terminal gives me a message:    mv: overwrite ‘./WRK/mahetzuo2.wrk’?

Comment: Good, that's because of  the `-i` option that we are using, it's trying to copy files with the same name in a same directory that's why it's asking about what it should do, you can answer it using `y/n`.

Comment: It looks that it move only from folder "1" all .wrk files what are in folder "1" and it's subfolders to WRK-folder. Perhaps there is some problem, because I have some duplicate .wrk files in other folders too.